# How do you have button choices in a UIPopOver?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

```
- (IBAction)openImagePicker:(id)sender //Makes UIImagePicker roll up from the bottom.
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        // We are using an iPhone
        UIActionSheet *alertSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Where do you want to get your daily image?" delegate:(self) cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Library", nil];
        [alertSheet setTag:0];
        [alertSheet setDelegate:self];
        [alertSheet showFromTabBar:[[self tabBarController] tabBar]];
        [alertSheet release];
    }
    else
    {
        // We are using an iPad
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        UIPopoverController *popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
        popoverController.delegate=self;
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So where it does the iPad part, what I want it to do is give you a choice between taking a new picture, and using one you already have, just like it does on the iPhone. Right now all it lets you do it choose one you already took.

Answer (score 0):

`UIActionSheet` has a method called `showFromBarButtonItem: animated:`. If you specify a bar button item, the action sheet will display in a popover on the iPad.